# Dart - Self hosted packages

Tags: documentation, dart, package

I am currently playing around with AngularDart client with a ASP.NET services and I am wanting to host a valid version of the client API for server itself. Since the server model has all the type and structure information about my requests, responses etc, I want to be able to generate a valid Dart client library rather than manually keep them in sync.

Dart documentation shows there is an option for ['hosted' packages](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/dependencies.html#hosted-packages) but I can't find any information about the specs the package server has to adhere to so that these packages can be added directly from the Dart editor.

I want to know if there is any official documentation for implementing a valid package server, or if there are any open source ports that could be used as a guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pub's package server is open source. You can clone the repo from [Github](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dartlang) and host your own copy on Google App Engine.

Comment: Clearly I'm not very good at finding things.. Thanks!

Comment: In your defense, the name of the repo and its description could be clearer that its for hosting pub packages.